# Renaming files in an Alfresco script

Tags: javascript, alfresco

I am struggling to write a script in Alfresco to rename file extension.

The file is saved as `filename.bin`. I am using content rules to say when filename equals `*bin` rename to `*pdf`.

I am struggling a bit with the script and would appreciate any help.

My script is as below:

```
// change the name of this document
document.properties.name = document.properties.name+".pdf";
// add a new property string
document.properties["cm:locale"] = mylocalenode;
// save the property modifications
document.save();
```

but doesn't seem to get me anywhere.

Comment: Please don't put "but doesnt seem to get me anywhere". That doesn't get us anywhere either :) ... could you show an error message, if any? It just doesn't seem to do anything? Have you checked your log?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The script as written would take a document named "filename.bin" and rename it to "filename.bin.pdf". It would then set a property called "cm:locale" equal to the value of mylocalenode, which appears to be
undefined in this snippet. I don't know what you are going for with the cm:locale so I will ignore that and give you a script that will search for the document named filename.bin and change its name.

If you would rather iterate over the children in a folder, you should be able to look at the Alfresco JavaScript API to figure out how to modify the snippet below to do that.

```
var results = search.luceneSearch("@cm\\:name:filename.bin");
var doc = results[0]; // assumes there is only one result, which may not be what you want
var oldName = doc.properties.name;
var newName = oldName.replace('.bin', '.pdf');
doc.properties.name = newName;
doc.save();
```

Comment: You should use doc.name = newName; since it also changes the childQNamePath internally used in the relation the parent in Alfresco (calls FileFolderService.rename()). Just setting the property name can result in inconsistent behaviour. This is a strange quirk of the ScriptNode API.

Answer (score 0):

Adding more in this,as you are using `content-rule`.There is no need to search document using lucene/solr service .We can directly access document object,it refers to document on which your rule is being executed.

So the code will be like below.

```
var oldName = document.properties.name;
var newName = oldName.replace('.bin', '.pdf');
document.properties.name = newName;
document.save();
```